# I failed this audit, but the question is Too Opinionated and Off-Topic

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

While going through the [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) tag per the meta post on burninating it (I could make another post about the harm of audits as they are today, namely interrupting useful work. SO employees: *please* stop interjecting filtered tags into random questions just so you can push audits on me), I came across [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7073614), and failed it.

Apparently, the proper course of action was to leave this open (meaning there are zero problems whatsoever with the post; any close choice other than Leave Open would have failed the audit).

However, this question is validly close-voted as either **Too Opinionated** ("Is there a sane way to do this?" That's 100% opinion), or as **Off-Topic** because it doesn't show any code, so there is no problem for us to solve. He talks in abstract about the code he might try, but doesn't show actual code used to attempt the desired outcome.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me.  That said, I've seen *far* worse questions and audits; they mention some code in the question, ten people felt it warranted upvoting, and two people felt it was clear enough to answer it.  Ignoring the "in a sane way", the question seems adequate enough.  I would have expected a little more details from a 36K+ user, but \*shrug*

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables The question referenced in that link is not visible to <10K users, by the way.

Comment: "In a sane way" is adequately defined by the rest of the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't agree (if it does, then edit the question to remove the opinionated question), but even if I did, that still leaves a lack of exemplary code, which is usually demanded for questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Code has never been a requirement for posting questions.  I've edited the question to remove the "sane" part.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay, if that's the case, then shouldn't the Off-Topic reason have its text referencing the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) How-To page removed. The one about "...must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** ..."

Comment: It's not a code troubleshooting question.  Questions *are* required to have enough information in them to be answerable, and it's pretty difficult to answer a code troubleshooting question without seeing the code.

Comment: Reviews with [haskell] tag, avoid you must.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In a way, I feel like it is. He has identified problems with a programming approach to something, and wants to know how to solve them. This is, by definition, troubleshooting. The only unique aspect of this question is that he doesn't seem to have written the code yet.

Comment: Having already written code is not a requirement for asking a question either, despite frequent protests by the community to the contrary.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Except it *is* a requirement for troubleshooting questions.

Comment: I'd link to "good subjective vs. bad subjective" but I'm too lazy.  This question is on the good side.  But probably shouldn't have been part of an audit, because it *is* subjective.

Comment: @Will, of course, had I come across this question any other time outside of the review queue, I probably would not have voted to close it (I don't read [tag:haskell] questions, anyway. But it shines a light on the problems we have with review audits being generated automatically instead of being hand-picked.

Comment: At the risk of encouraging pedantry run amok, yes, code is a requirement for troubleshooting questions.  This is not a troubleshooting question, and I don't wish to split hairs any further.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree, then. In the meantime I will continue interpreting words by their definitions.

Comment: Just make sure you understand the words.  It's not like this is all that difficult.  There's plenty of common sense precedence, both here and on the main site, to guide your actions, and (based on the community votes given on that question) your opinion is clearly at odds with the community gestalt.

Comment: Community precedence (and how often it is ignored by site moderators or site owners) is not the point of contention here. The ultimate point of this question is one of an inherently flawed audit system.

Answer (score 6):

I don't agree that this is a troubleshooting question.  I am somewhat familiar with Haskell, but unfamiliar with the library the OP in the linked question is asking about.  To me, the question reads as a "how do I do X in the context of Y" type question.  The OP's code works fine, they just want to add a feature, but are uncertain how to write an efficient implementation.

I do agree that the question is lazily written (no pun intended).  As a consideration to others who are here to provide a solution or because they're looking to solve the same problem, the OP *should have provided code*.

- As an answerer, I don't want to have to write out a bunch of boilerplate, which may or may not resemble what the OP is actually doing, before I can start helping this person
- As someone trying to solve the same problem, there is a good chance the answers won't even be helpful to me if I don't even understand as much as the OP does (I have my B, but how do I get A?)

While the question is of lower quality than I like to see asked (particularly by someone with that kind of rep), I don't feel that there is a legitimate reason to close this particular question.